# Append (self) with stacks in Python classes

Tags: python, oop, data-structures

I am doing/learning data structures and algorithms and I came across the following code:

```
class BinaryTree:

    def __init__(self, root_data):
        self.data = root_data
        self.left_child = None
        self.right_child = None

    def inorder_iterative(self):
        inorder_list = []
        return inorder_list

    def get_right_child(self):
        return self.right_child

    def get_left_child(self):
        return self.left_child

    def set_root_val(self, obj):
        self.data = obj

    def get_root_val(self):
        return self.data

    def preorder_iterative(self):
        pre_ordered_list = [] #use this as result
        stack = []
        stack.append(self)

        while len(stack)>0:
            node = stack.pop() #should return a value 
            pre_ordered_list.append(node.get_root_val())
            if node.right_child:
                stack.append(node.get_right_child())
            if node.left_child:
                stack.append(node.get_left_child())
        return pre_ordered_list


    bn = BinaryTree(1)
    bn.left_child = BinaryTree(2)
    bn.right_child = BinaryTree(3)
    print (bn.preorder_iterative())
```

I am very lost about `stack.append(self)` part. I am not sure what is the point of having this line and I don't fully understand the concept of `.append(self)`. I have learnt that `self` represents the instance of the class.

Comment: It's just simulating recursion using an explicit stack. Each iteration removes the top of the stack (starting with the tree itself), processes it, and pushes any children on the top to be processed next.

Comment: But I never call `preorder_iterative` recursively. In my understanding, once I do `print (bn.preorder_iterative())`, I get in that method and because of `len(stack)>0`, I stay in that particular loop, until my stack is empty. I don't get a chance to re-call that method recursively.

Comment: You don't *need* to; each time the value of `node` changes, you are effectively "recursing" into a subtree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of the stack is to simulate recursion.

The initial value placed on the stack is the tree itself (in the form of its root node). Its value is retrieved, and then each subtree is placed on the stack. On the next iteration of the loop, the left child is removed, processed, and replaced with *its* children, if any. The loop continues as long as there is anything on the stack to process. Once everything on the left side of the tree as been processed, you'll finally start on the right child (placed the stack way at the beginning of the loop).

Compare to a recursive version:

```
def preorder_recursive(self):
    result = [self.get_root_val()]
    if node.left_child:
        result.extend(node.left_child.preorder_recursive())
    if node.right_child:
        result.extend(node.right_child.preorder_recursive())
    return result
```

Each recursive call essentially puts `self` on a stack, allowing the left child (and its descendants) to be processed before eventually returning to the root and moving to its right child.

Comment: I see. So `stack.append(self)` just adds the root to the stack, correct? In this case, after `stack.append(self)`, we get `1` in the stack

Comment: Right. Each node is the root of *some* (sub)tree; `self` is the root of the tree which actually called `preorder_iterative`; the rest of the roots come from calls to `get_*_child`.